# Trying to make a simple math equation in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a simple function that gets 2 variables from the user (x,y)
 
makes a calculation, and prints it out. 
 
for some reason without success:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Insert Number1"
    x <- readLn
    putStrLn "Insert Number2"
    y <- readLn
    z = (x * y * 0.01)
    putStrLn "Result: " ++z
```

The Error I get:

```
test.hs:6:11: parse error on input `='
```

Comment: That particular error is because You need to prefix your `z = ...` definition with a `let` keyword.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `let` to bind new variables. You also have a few errors on the final line: first, you must explicitly convert between `Double` and `String` (using, for example, `show`), and secondly, you need to remember precedence. In Haskell, function application binds tighter than anything except record updates, so what you wrote parses as `(putStrLn "Result: ") ++ z`, which doesn't really make sense. With these things fixed:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Insert Number1"
    x <- readLn
    putStrLn "Insert Number2"
    y <- readLn
    let z = x * y * 0.01
    putStrLn ("Result: " ++ show z)
```

Comment: a really cool thing that the haskell compiler can deduce the type of `x` and `y` by the type of `0.01` and the function `(*)`. otherwise you would have to specify it with `x <- readLn :: IO Double` and `y <- readLn :: Io Double`

Comment: sily question: I tried to run ":load test.hs" and nothing happened, how am I suppose to input the x and y variables?

Comment: @Asaf After you've loaded the file, run `main`.